# Keras fully connected layer for CIFAR-10 RGB image

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, keras

I am using Keras to make a network that takes the CIFAR-10 RGB images as input. 
I want a first layer that is fully connected (not a convoluted layer).

I create my model like below. I'm specifying the input as 3 (channels) x 32 x 32 (pixels)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_shape=(3,32,32),kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
```

I keep getting this error `__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)`

I would prefer not to Flatten the input as later on I want to have the layers work on different channels.

Comment: This contradicts current state-of-the-art approaches (which more or less follows the idea of feature-extraction -> non-linear mapping) and i hope you got a good reason for this. Dense-layers are usually defined on flattened-representations and if you do not want to have this flattened view, there has to be a layer before that to split those dimensions somehow (at least that's my non-expert interpretation of keras' workings). Also keep in mind, that this dense-layer might be huge (in this case maybe 1M weights for this one layer; usually a bad thing) depending on the exact layout.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, but regarding the error, you should provide how many neurons you want in the `Dense` layer. I think that is why there is an error. Again, what are you exactly trying to do? Do you want to connect each image block densely to a layer, or the entire image?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I want to connect each RGB channel, so I want 3 densely connected layers (1 dense layer for each channel). Then I want to use the outputs of that as a 3D tensor.
Also, I agree that I probably shouldn't be doing this, but I'm testing some theories and comparing results

Comment: Ok. So if the image size is `m x n`, then you can connect the first channel to a dense layer containing `m x n` neurons. Then use `reshape` to convert back into `m x n`. Do this for the other channels and then use concatenate to create an `m x n x 3` tensor.